# make menu stay once clicked even if a link is clicked to go to another page

Tags: jquery

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.menu").click(function() {
    $("#mp-menu").show();
    });
});
```

HTML code

```
<a class="icon icon-display" class ="menu" href="#">Test</a>
```

Hi all. The code above I am using to pop the menu div from the side of the browser. What I want is once the menu has popped out after it has been activated by a click, it should stay docked to the side of the screen even if another link on the page is clicked and goes to another page. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

When the menu is opened or closed, set a cookie indicating the state of the menu. On page load of any page, check the cookie and set the state of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

This will use `localStorage` to preserve the state of the menu, but it doesn't handle it closing as you've not mentioned what causes that to occur...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.menu").click(function() {
        $("#mp-menu").show();
        localStorage.setItem("show-mp-menu", true);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem("show-mp-menu")) {
        $("#mp-menu").show();
    }
});
```

However you trigger closing or hiding the menu, it would need to do something like this...

```
$("#mp-menu").hide();
localStorage.setItem("show-mp-menu", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

to do this it's either you will use Iframe or asynchronously generate the content. So that even when you click a link on the content, it will only change the content and not the whole page, drawback is the URL but can be fixed by using history.pushState or replaceState and manipulate onload for directed access URL.

If you truly insist on your goal and way, you can set a cross-page 'flag' for tracking the event across different pages such as cookies and session. I suggest it is best to use cookies. 
Use jQuery cookie for ease.

> ```
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>         var flag = $.cookie('flag');
>         $("a.menu").click(function() {
>             // this is for toggling the menu bar
>             if( !flag ) {
>             // When flag is not set, when button is clicked show menu
>                 $("#mp-menu").show();
>                 $.cookie('flag', true);
>             } else {
>                 // otherwise, hide it
>                 $("#mp-menu").hide();
>                 $.removeCookie('flag');
>             }
>         });
>         if( flag ) {
>             // remove cookie, so it will be set when the button is clicked
>             // since menu will only be shown once the flag is not set
>             // so it is important to remove it
>             $.removeCookie('flag');
>             $("a.menu").click();
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think the way you explained it is exactly how I want to implement the pages where only the content of the pages change by use of include files basically cutting up the pages content into sections.

Comment: then design your website with this:
header,
links,
iframe(for content),
footer.

give ID to your iframe, and put target="<id of the iframe>" on your menu links(except for those inside the content, because they will automatically target the iframe, only apply this to the external links such as for the header, footer, and links sections)